# How to copy Image from on workbook to another which is generated at run time

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook 'w1'. I have a code inside a button which copies the data from book 'w1' to a new book 'w2'. Here book 'w2' is generated when the button is pressed. Now I want to copy an image form 'w1' to 'w2' using the same button. Below is the code that I wrote inside the button to copy the image from  'w1' to 'w2'. But its throwing an error "object dosen't support this property or method"

```
W1.Sheets("conf").Shapes("Image1").Copy
w2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(w2.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(20, 1), w2.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(21, 1))_         
.Paste
```

Does it copies the image with same size and shape or fits it in range of cells entered

Comment: What is the `"some error"`?  Also, what workbook is `Range("A1")` referencing?

Comment: `Range Object` have no `.Paste` Method. That is what might be causing your problem.

Comment: The error is "object dosen't support this property or method", that range("A1") was by mistake written over there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
w2.Sheets("Sheet1").Paste
```

Comment: Hey thanks it is working now, <b>one more help:</b> can you tell me how to move this picture to some specific cell and move it little left or right

Comment: I am using    </br>                                                                     `Public Sub Example()
    MoveShape w2.Shapes("Image1"), Range("d4")
End Sub`      </br>                                                           But how to run this function automatically so that it works

Comment: Both Shapes and Cells have `Top` and `Left` properties: you can use those to position the shape.

Comment: Huh, finally done now I'm using this                                                                                                                                                                                                                               `W1.Sheets("conf").Shapes("Image1").Copy
  w2.Sheets("Sheet1").Paste
  
  w2.Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes.Range(Array("Image1")).Select
  Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft -240
  Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementTop -380`                                                                                                Thanks everyone...